# Why the python enviroment isn't provided by pyenv。

Tags: python-3.x, pyenv

I use pyenv manage my python versions.
But I found when i install package by pip, The errors below:

```py
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
```

Why the python enviroment isn't provided by pyenv。
Therefore, errors are often reported due to import package

Comment: have you activated the environment? the location in your error seems to be the global location not from your environment.

Comment: I use commend `pyenv global 3.7.4` had switched env.

  system
* 3.7.4 (set by /home/ease/.pyenv/version)